# Pose Shim: Test runs indefinitely

Tags: c#, unit-testing, shim

I'm trying to use Pose (see https://github.com/tonerdo/pose) to shim an instance method of the XDocument class, as follows:

Code under test:

```
/// <exception cref="ArgumentException" />
public void Persist<T>(XDocument document) where T : IEntity
{
    if (!HasRegistration(typeof(T))) throw new ArgumentException("oops");

    try
    {
        var filePath = filePaths[typeof(T)];
        document.Save(filePath);
    }
    catch (System.IO.IOException)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(50);
        Persist<T>(document);
        throw;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

Unit test:

```
[TestMethod()]
public void PersistenceService_Persist_T_Works() 
{
    var saved = false;

    var mockFileSystem = new Mock<IFileSystem>();
    mockFileSystem.Setup(T => T.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).Returns("");
    mockFileSystem.Setup(T => T.Directory.GetParent(It.IsAny<string>())).CallBase();
    mockFileSystem.Setup(T => T.Directory.GetParent(It.IsAny<string>()).Parent.FullName).Returns("");

    var persister = new PersistenceService(mockFileSystem.Object);

    var xDoc = new XDocument();

    Shim xDocumentShim = Shim
        .Replace(() => xDoc.Save(Is.A<string>()))
        .With(delegate (XDocument @this, string s) { saved = true; });

    Assert.IsFalse(saved);
    persister.Persist<IEducationEntity>(xDoc);
    Assert.IsTrue(saved);
}
```

My intent is for, when xDoc.Save(string) is called in the code under test, to have a callback to the unit test to flip the saved flag.

The test runs for a few minutes than aborts due to stack overflow.

Any pointers on what I'm getting wrong?

Comment: could be infinite recursion as you call `Persist` within the `catch`. If error occurs each time it will recall the error prone method.

Comment: the `Setup` of `IFileSystem` is also flawed as an interface has no base to call so `.CallBase();` has no reason to be configured.

Comment: One of those statements in the try-catch is causing an exception to be thrown. Start there.

Comment: @Nkosi, thanks, good catches. After commenting out the recursion, it looks like an IO exception. I'll post what the end solution is.

Comment: How is this for Pose when it uses Mock?